# How do you implement a drop down list in prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, xpce

I am currently implementing a criminal expert system. This system will determine whether someone is a criminal or not.

Is there anyway to implement a drop down list in swi prolog using xpce??

Comment: I am not fully sure on the approach to do. I normally  just use the menu class from xpce which provides a check box style for list

Comment: So what happened when you tried the normal approach?